# Class reference is taken from different jar

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

There are some classes used in a java program referred from `abc` package from `xyz.jar`. The package is imported in the java file.

Also the same class is in other `lmn.jar`.

So if I delete the jar file from the project, i should be getting the error.

But the class compiles and takes the class from the other `lmn.jar`.

**Eg.**

`weblogic.jdbc.oci.Blob` is a class in `weblogic.jar`

But if i delete `weblogic.jar`, it takes it from `java.sql.Blob`.

I don't want this to happen, the program should display error.

Answer (score 0):

In such a case you can use fully qualified name of class, which will include package name. For example, instead of:

```
Blob blob = new Blob();
```

You can write:

```
weblogic.jdbc.oci.Blob blob = new weblogic.jdbc.oci.Blob();
```

Comment: Actually, the project is already developed and we would be replacing weblogic with webshpere.
So to manually write the statement everywhere is not possible now.

Answer (score 0):

When importing a class you are also defining the package. So when you import "weblogic.jdbc.oci.Blob" and remove this class from classpath it will not automatically import it from a different package unless you change the import statement as well. 
Some IDEs might automatically try to resolve classes and add the missing import statements. Maybe check that.

Comment: Yes, i have already removed the jar from the classpath. But have not removed the import statements.
Cant remove the import statements as the project is very large and have lot of dependencies.

Need to stop the Eclipse IDE for automatic resolving the imports.
can you help with the same ?

Answer (score 0):

For one of the case try to use the entire path, ie

For example if you need Blob from `weblogic.jar`

then try to call `weblogic.jdbc.oci.Blob  bl = ...`